# Can't flash recovery image

Tags: ubuntu-touch, flash

I'm working about a month now on turning my BQ Aquaris E4.5 Android edition into an Ubuntu Edition.

unfortunatly I always get this error:

```
    2015/04/25 14:35:20 Device is |krillin|
    2015/04/25 14:35:21 Flashing version 21 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-     aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
    2015/04/25 14:35:21 ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09 is a channel alias to ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
    67.41 MB / 67.41 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 1.70 MB/s 
    60.40 MB / 60.40 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 1.48 MB/s 
    286.68 MB / 286.68 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 2.94 MB/s 
    /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en/krillin/version-21.tar.xz
    /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz
    /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz
    /root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-0142302186687e3e48e6987283f6caf5d471a4160f98aa6a3cb7658f96471297.tar.xz
2015/04/25 14:37:18 Can't flash recovery image
```

however, on my device screen (fastboot) it says: `Partition 'recovery' not support flash

how do I get around this and flash ubuntu-touch to it

Answer (score 1):

The Android version of the phone needs to be repartitioned before Ubuntu can be installed on it.

You can follow [How to Install Ubuntu on bq Aquaris e4.5](http://www.androidheadlines.com/2015/02/install-ubuntu-phone-os-onto-bq-aquaris-e4-5-smartphone.html), to get your phone configured such that you can flash Ubuntu onto it with *ubuntu-device-flash*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
unfortunatly, the flashtool provided in that tutorial doesn't work (it shows no indication that it's doing anything)

Comment: F.y.i [This](http://gyazo.com/6ebf54e35a8e28fe3c80a9283b608e52) is how the flashtool looks like after hitting download
device is almost completely off (it only shows a 'charging' screen but I can't get rid of that)

Comment: wohoooo it works :D

I had to turnoff the phone, start the tool, click download and THEN connect the phone...